# Process Id of Chomium-browser not showing in terminal

Tags: linux, bash, shell, browser, chromium

I am writing a bash script and I need to kill any browser running at the time of script execution. For that I want the process id of every browser running in the background. I tried all the following, but nothing worked.  [See this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84Q5u.jpg)

pidof chromium

pidof chromium-browser

pgrep chromium-browser

ps -A | grep chromium-browser

ps -aux | grep chromium-browser | grep pid

However,  [See this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYQWE.jpg) . It worked for firefox browser. Can Anyone figure out If it's something wrong with command or Chromium-browser itself. Also Can anyone tell any other method to get the process id. I shall try that out by the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following piece of script to list all pids of processes containing `chromium-browser` in their command name :

```
ps -aux | grep chromium-browser |  tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

Your other commands didn't work because the process running for `chromium-browser` is `/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromium-browser` (at least for me on xubuntu). You can check the real process by typing `ps -aux`.

**Note:** weirdly enough, `pgrep chromium-browser` doesn't return anything, but `pgrep chromium` and `pgrep chromium-browse` work just fine.

`pgrep -f chromium-browser` is also good

Comment: Well thanks, that helped a lot.Can you tell why above commands didn't worked particularly **pidof**. Was I missing something ?

Comment: @C0deDaedalus updated my answer to address your comment

Answer (score 1):

Have similar issue. The reason for this is that executable file named `chrome`. (I'm using chromium via snap on Ubuntu 18.04)

```
/snap/chromium/861/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome --type=renderer --field-trial-handle=17044127674507841828,2715256006050366173,131072 --lang=en-US --extension-process --enable-auto-reload --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --service-request-channel-token=10676003778996199464 --renderer-client-id=7 --no-v8-untrusted-code-mitigations --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100,v8_natives_data:101
```

So, use `chrome` for you query.
Or if you'd like to use `chromium-browser` you need to use additional match options, like `pgrep -f`.